# How to save a _flutterFFmpeg gif in firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, gif

Edit:
After some changes with help from @Frank van Puffelen
I getting  a new error see below updated code and updated error

Hello everyone im trying to save a gif which I create with flutter_ffmpeg: ^0.4.2
With this code im trying to create a gif of picked video from user which is currently widget.videopathasstring
THis is the path of picked video.

```
 Directory gifDirectory;
  String gifOutputFile;
  getpreviewvideo() async {
    String currentvideo = widget.videopathasstring;
    await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((directory) {
      print("13");
      gifDirectory = Directory(directory.path + '/gif');
      print("14");
      gifDirectory.exists().then((exists) async {
        print("0");
        if (!exists) {
          print("1");
          await gifDirectory.create();
        }
      }).then((value) => {
            print("3"),
            gifOutputFile = gifDirectory.path +
                '/' +
                DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() +
                '.gif',
          });
    });
    print("4");
    var arguments = [
      '-i',
      currentvideo,
      '-t',
      '2.5',
      '-ss',
      '2.0',
      '-f',
      'gif',
      gifOutputFile,
    ];
    _flutterFFmpeg.executeWithArguments(arguments).then((rc) {
      print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc");
    });

    return File(gifOutputFile);
  }
```

The problem is im getting this error

```
GTMSessionFetcher invoking fetch callbacks, data {length = 0, bytes = 0x}, error (null)
2
GTMSessionFetcher invoking fetch callbacks, data {length = 613, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 226e616d 65223a20 22616c6c ... 36316263 34220a7d }, error (null)
flutter: 13
flutter: 14
flutter: 4
flutter: Invalid argument(s) (path): Must not be null
flutter: 0
-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dc5f0558
flutter: 3
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dc5f0558'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x181e8904c 0x19a4fdf54 0x181f66014 0x181e1e474 0x181e1d5b0 0x181e15410 0x181e0d0a0 0x100e3c4b8 0x100e3b324 0x100e3bb24 0x10065528c 0x181af9914 0x181afb660 0x181afe788 0x181b0cdd0 0x181b0d5f8 0x1f212a0b8 0x1f2129e94)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
* thread #65, queue = 'com.apple.root.default-qos', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001b8cd0964 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x1b8cd0964 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1b8cd0984               ; <+40>
    0x1b8cd0968 <+12>: pacibsp
    0x1b8cd096c <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1b8cd0970 <+20>: mov    x29, sp
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Hope anyone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not uploading the file to Cloud Storage, which only happens once you call `putFile`.

Have a look at the FlutterFire documentation on [uploading files](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#uploading-files) for an example of how to use `putFile`

Comment: Yes i know but the problem is . this package needs a uploaddirectory directly inside the arguments which is in my case gifOutputfile. Which is a directory inside firebase storage. But its not getting saved. So what i can i ido? Normally first arguments should be created and then execute function should be called and then i should get the file to upload it and get the downloadurl .but the package does not work like that i think. So i dont understand how i can save this file .

Comment: I updated my code and new error please check out.

Comment: This looks like a new problem, so I wouldn't recommend bringing closure here and opening a new question. The stack trace is hard to parse, but it seems a null pointer exception somewhere: "Must not be null".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70280933/nsnull-length-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x1dc5f0558-while-tryin        I have created a new one